# Can Keras be used to build clustering models

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, keras

The `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn` module can be used to build `KerasClassifier` model.

Can `Keras` be used to build clustering models?

If it can be, are there any examples for that?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want, autoencoders are an example of that. What clustering algorithm do attempt to use?

Comment: you know i want to use some features like age, city, education, company, job title and so on  to cluster people into some groups and to get the key features of each group.

Comment: Deep Learning tools generally *suck* at clustering. At best they include the *slowest variant* of k-means. One of the least useful methods. I doubt you find one that has, e.g., DBSCAN. Or even any of the fast k-means variants. Or OPTICS. Or support for other distance functions such as Canberra.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Keras to build clustering algorithms. Recalling that Keras is a high-level api for Tensorflow or Theano, and that you can build a K-means algorithm (very well known clustering technique) in Tensorflow, you should be able to build it in Keras. Example (in tensorflow):https://learningtensorflow.com/lesson6/.

Nevertheless, sklearn has in-built clustering algorithms like K-means or Gaussian Mixture Models, so at first, I think a better approach is using these sklearn funcionalities.

Comment: There is no "KNN clustering". There is kNN classification and k-means clustering. That should tell you something about the reliability of that blog post.

Comment: Edited: following @Anony-Mousse